# How to use static const field of a base class as size of an array in functions of a derived class?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, constants

I have a hyerarchy of classes. Methods of these classes may create temporary static arrays of the same size. I want to set size as `static const` field of the base class.

I put declaration of the field in a heared file and initialized it in a source file. This works without issues when compiled using GCC 4.3 but fails with VS compiler.

Base.h

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void function();

protected:
    static const int size;
};
```

Base.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"

const int Base::size = 128;

void Base::function()
{
    int array[size];
}
```

Derived.h

```
#include "Base.h"

class Derived : public Base
{
    void function();
};
```

Derived.cpp

```
#include "Derived.h"

void Derived::function()
{
    int array[size];
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Derived.h"

int main()
{
    Base* object = new Derived();
    object->function();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that `size` would be initialized in Base.cpp and considered as const in Derived.cpp. But it works only with GCC compiler.
Visual Studio shows the following error messages:

error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol

note: see usage of 'size'

Comment: I don't think it should work, since when compile `Derived::function`, `size` is still unknown (any maybe even impossible to determine in compile time). (although I'm not sure what the standard say)

Comment: does this have something to do with `variable length array`?

Comment: GCC has a [VLA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) extension which is why it works. You should make `size` `constexpr` and initialize it in `Base` declaration.

Answer (score 3):

A constant variable can only be used in a constant expression after its initialisation has been encountered (and is a constant initialiser). `Base::size` hasn't been initialised in Derived.cpp, so it cannot be used in a constant expression (such as length of the array): The program is ill-formed.

> How to use static const field of a base class as size of an array in functions of a derived class?

Initialise the size within the class declaration, and declare it constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, a GCC extension makes this compile successfully. The problem is easily fixable by removing

```
const int Base::size = 128;
```

And change the `Base::size` (in .h) to

```
static constexpr int Base::size = 128;
```

This makes sure Base::size can be evaluated at compile-time. If you want to be have more influence on the value of `size`, templates can be used:

```
template <int N>
class Base {
    protected: static constexpr int size = N;
};
```

called through

```
Base<10>::size; // returns 10
Base<128>::size; // returns 128

using my_base = Base<128>;
my_base::size; // returns 128
```